# Is it possible to change the date format of mobile date input in Material Datepicker?

Tags: android, material-ui, datepicker, material-design

[image: mobile date input]

Is there a way to change the date format in the Material Datepicker while switching to "mobile date input"? I have gone through every documentation and article but I couldn't find any solution.

[image: input type]

Currently, when I switch it to input mode it formatted as `MM/dd/yy` but what I want is `yyyy-MM-dd`